# I just want to know how to show the forgotten password using other data from MSAccess Database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

```
private void RevealForgetPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/rallf/Documents/dctcaccount.mdb";
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
            cn.Open();
            string selectString = "select * from tbl_account where [Username]=@user and [Secret_Question]=@sq and [Secret_Answer]=@sa and [Pin]=@pin";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@user", txtbox_username.Text.ToLower()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@sq", cmbox_secquestion.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@sa", txtbox_secretans.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pin", txtbox_pin.Text));
            cmd.CommandText = selectString;
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



             int count = 0;
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 count = count + 1;



             }
             if (count == 1)
             {

                 panel2.Visible = true;
                 lbl_username.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
```

Here's where the error is when I run the program.(the panel will show saying hello to the user and then showing his/her forgotten pass.)

```
lbl_password.Text = reader["Password"].ToString();
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Invalid Account!");
                 cn.Close();
             }
             }
```

the error says this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No data exists for
>   the row/column.

I have tried different ways of including `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(" "))`
They also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't store Passwords! Just store their Hash!**

Then let the user create a new password if needed.

To solve your error:
You have to fetch the data inside the loop`while (reader.Read())`.After the loop its too late, because you reached the end of`OleDbDataReader`and can't go back (forward only).

```cs
int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
    {
         count = count + 1;
         string username = reader.item["Username"].ToString();
         string password = reader.item["Password"].ToString();
    }
```